# The underlying provider failed on Open the database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got the error The underlying provider failed on Open like this while using the code first approach in mvc

my controller code is

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SchoolDbContext schoolDbContext = new SchoolDbContext();
    Student student = new Student() { Name = "New Student" };
    schoolDbContext.Students.Add(student);
    schoolDbContext.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

and web.config file code is

`<add name="SchoolDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;User Id=sa;Password=*******;Initial Catalog=StudentDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />`

Comment: Sometime it does that try Install-Package EntityFramework on Package Manager console after selecting the project.

Comment: I did like that only but getting error

Answer (score 0):

When you are using code first approach then you have to define SchoolDbContext class and inherited DBContext Class.
like this

```
public class SchoolDbContext : DBContext
{
   public DBSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
}



 public ActionResult Index()
    {
     SchoolDbContext schoolDbContext = new SchoolDbContext();
     Student student = new Student() { Name = "New Student" };
     student.name = "";// set the property here
     student.age =""; // set the property here
     schoolDbContext.Students.Add(student);
     schoolDbContext.SaveChanges();
     return View();
    }
```